# how to get started in p2p networking programming?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I want to learn how to write a software using a peer to peer networking architecture but i don't know where to start, knowing that I use as a programming languages : c/c++ , lisp, a little of python. any pointer to documentation or tutorials is appreciated.

Comment: Learn how to do ordinary socket programming first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just start with a Bittorrent API, such as https://github.com/JosephSalisbury/python-bittorrent, rather than writing your own.

After you have gained experience with a well-used P2P network, then you may start to see what you could do better, then start to write your own.

Comment: Link is broken, fyi

Answer (score 2):

here are some [guidelines](http://cs.berry.edu/~nhamid/p2p/index.html) which i found with google